# Can Sublime Text show filenames when using Ctrl+Tab to browse opened files?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-2

Is there a way to show the list of files when I browse the open files using ctrl+tab keyboard shortcuts.

It can be useful in selecting an appropriate file easily and visually. Not a deal-breaker but can be pretty handy.

Notepad++ can do that. Here is the screenshot. I could not find a similar feature in ST. [image]

Answer (score 0):

SynWrite has Ctrl+Tab window like this (option must be On)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for this feature in Sublime Text. I know that Notepad++ also have this feature.